# How can my outlook addin know when a link or an image is clicked in the body of an email message?

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-addin

I would like my outlook application add-in to respond to the user clicking a link in the body of an email message.  My add-in might then cancel that navigation so that the link is not followed.

Alternatively, I would like my add-in to know when a particular image is clicked in the body of an email message.

Are either of these possible?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for that.

Comment: Are there any events for anything that the user does inside an email that he or she is viewing?

Comment: No, the Outlook object model doesn't provide any. But Outlook uses Word as an email editor. So, you can try handling Word's events. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196.aspx) property returns an instance of the Document class which represents the message body.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll look into that. Using the WordEditor property, might it be possible to respond to a user clicking a link or an image in an email?